# transference of migrated answers

Tags: discussion, migration

Yesterday, I answered [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28538/high-school-double-lens-optics-question) on Math.SE and Zev migrated it to Physics.SE. The OP had an account there, and Zev commented that "If you need help associating an account on physics.SE, you can flag your question for moderator attention". The question has since been associated with the OP's Physics.SE account.

I created an account there and flagged my answer for moderator attention, asking that the answer be associated with my account. It has been several hours, but my answer has not been so associated. Is it possible to do this with an answer, or should I stop pressing the issue?

**Amendment:**

I just got a comment from dmckee$\,\blacklozenge$ that "Fixing the situation outlined in your flag is beyond the power of a diamond moderator. For the moment I am waiting to see if some daily script will correct the situation. Once it is clear that this will not happen, I will escalate to the team."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've restored your profile's association with the answer. Moderators can't do this directly, but they can always get in touch with someone from the team, or you can email us directly using the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know under whose purview this action fell. I didn't see any discussion regarding the association of the OP's question and their account, so I had assumed that, as Zev suggested, the OP flagged the Physics.SE moderators, and they fixed it. I thought the same might work for answers. Your answer will help prevent such confusion in the future.

Comment: Normally the association happens automatically after the account is created, @robjohn. It worked for the asker here, but not you. When it fails, someone on the SE team has to manually fix it up.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Perhaps this situation had to do with the fact that my Physics.SE account was not created until after the question had been migrated.